# Flutter version on IOS stuck at 1.0.0

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

When I run:

```
pod outdated
```

on IOS to determine any pods that are outdated I get the following result:

```
.... 

Analyzing dependencies
The color indicates what happens when you run `pod update`
<green>  - Will be updated to the newest version
<blue>   - Will be updated, but not to the newest version because of specified version in Podfile
<red>    - Will not be updated because of specified version in Podfile

The following pod updates are available:
- Flutter 1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (latest version 1.3.300)
- Protobuf 3.9.2 -> 3.9.2 (latest version 3.10.0-rc1)
```

While version 1.0.0 of Flutter (in red) seems to be okay at the moment on IOS can someone please suggest how I can update this Pod?

I have upgraded Flutter using:

```
/Users/bob/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter upgrade
```

The above command seems to make no difference per the pod version noted above.  I would prefer everything be at the latest version but if it is not necessary knowing that information would be helpful as well.

Using:

```
/Users/bob/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter doctor -v
```

reveals:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.2 at /Users/bob/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision 2d2a1ffec9 (3 weeks ago), 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/bob/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • 08EB7508-34DE-4797-8F33-3DEE671742E4 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-0 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the podhelper.rb script (`YOUR_PATH//flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb`). It generates a 'fake' Flutter.podspec file but it hardcodes the 1.0.0 podspec.

Resolve this by editing lines 155-190 of podspec.rb (for iOS app), replacing the json definitions for the podspec with the version you want to move to from the CocoaPods repo (e.g. [here for v2.5](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/c/0/4/Flutter/2.5/Flutter.podspec.json)). Run pod update and it will update to 2.5.

The next section in the script repeats the same error for macOS apps so you may need to repeat for lines 193-228.

Comment: Clarification from the Flutter dev on GitHub. The Flutter POD version is irrelevant as the Flutter SDK includes the framework and is local. So you can safely ignore the outdated version message as long as you have Flutter at the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am testing this right now but if you navigate into `app_project/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec` you will see there is Flutter version hardcoded to 1.0.0

Now I am no expert in Flutter so I don't know if you are supposed to manually change this, to what version you should change it, if it even makes any difference and why flutter don't provide script when you perform flutter upgrade to also update this file and flutter version.

Comment: I believe the file you refer to is created by the file mentioned in the solution above.  Appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Update your podhelper.rb on this path to update Flutter version on iOS.
YOUR_PATH//flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb

s.name             = 'Flutter'
s.version          = '3.0.0'

Flutter 1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (latest version 3.0.0)